# Calculate previous calendar period

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, timestamp

I have two timestamps: start/end of period (calendar month, week or day).

I need to calculate previous period (previous month, week etc.). I tried to do it using `LocalDateTime` functions. E.g. using `getMonthOfYear() - 1` for month period but what to do with last day (beforeDayTo)?

E.g. september's `getDayOfMonth()` returns 30, but for previous period (august) I need 31 etc.

```
Long fromDateMillis = 1440277200000L;
Long toDateMillis = 1440363599000L;

LocalDateTime fromLocalDate = new LocalDateTime(fromDateMillis);
LocalDateTime toLocalDate = new LocalDateTime(toDateMillis)

int beforeYear = fromLocalDate.getYear();
int beforeMonthFrom = fromLocalDate.getMonthOfYear() - 1;
int beforeMonthTo = toLocalDate.getMonthOfYear() - 1;
int beforeDayFrom = fromLocalDate.getDayOfMonth();
int beforeDayTo = toLocalDate.getDayOfMonth();
Timestamp prevFromDate = Timestamp
        .valueOf(java.time.LocalDateTime.of(beforeYear, beforeMonthFrom, 1, 0, 0, 0));
Timestamp prevToDate = Timestamp
        .valueOf(java.time.LocalDateTime.of(beforeYear, beforeMonthTo, beforeDayTo, 0, 0, 0));
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: It is not clear what is your expected output and what you get instead. [mcve]

Comment: @Lay`O Please tell what you are expecting and what you are getting instead?

Comment: @Dante E.g. I expect previous period 01.08.2015 - 31.08.2015 but getting 01.08.2015 - 30.08.2015 instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the number of Day of the current month.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp);
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
cal.getTimeInMillis();
```

The last line give you the timestanp as a Long. So you can do it :

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Calendar alow you to do all what you want to do.
Take a look to this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html